# Database usage using stORM (ORM lightweight ORM for Android SQLite)

Tags: android, database

To understand the usage of stORM by David Chandler, i built a sample app to just insert and fetch the values from the database.

Project is like this:

I have one EditText where i enter name and click on a Button(INSERT). this should insert the name into the database.

I have another button(FETCH) which should fetch all the names from the database when clicked and print to Logcat.

Thats all.

I have made the project setup and included all the .jar files required. insert is working fine but i dont know how to fetch the names in the database and display it to the Logcat.

my activity where I perform insert and fetch.

```
package com.example.stormdemo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.stormdemo.dao.PersonDao;
import com.example.stormdemo.dao.PersonTable;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    long my_id = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText e_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        final PersonDao dao = new PersonDao(this);
        final Person newPerson = new Person();

        final PersonTable pt = new PersonTable();

        Button insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInsert);
        Button fetch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFetch);
        Button clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);

        insert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = e_name.getText().toString();

                newPerson.setName(name);
                System.out.println(name);

                long newPersonId = dao.insert(newPerson);

                my_id = newPersonId;

                System.out.println(my_id);

            }
        });

        fetch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Person p = dao.get(my_id);

                List<Person> list = dao.listAll();

                int ind = list.indexOf(list.iterator());

                System.out.println(p.getName());
            }
        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dao.deleteAll();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Were you successful using this stORM by now? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Gopinath No. from David M Chandler we came to know that stORM is too beta. So we dropped our idea of using stORM

Comment: actually stORM is very beautiful to use. I tried to use the DAO pattern in my code but then I came to know about this stORM, I loved the library as a whole. Reduces lot of work for us. :)

You can re-attempt to learn the library. Its pretty simple to setup and to use. Read my experiences here: http://tmblr.co/ZI_gpvYUgHN7

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fU17zdW9Ks   I am working on almost the same thing. I want to store a android Location type into the database and the link above is a good start but my question is are you storing text like a string or XML button? Storm allows you to wright a custom type converter but I have not figured that out yet.